# Getting Number Format Exception while converting String to Integer

Tags: java, numberformatexception

I am writing a code for converting a number given in string to integer. But it gives Number Format Exception for more than 9 digit number.  Is there any other way for doing this.

```
public class StringToInt {

public static void main(String args[])
{
    try
    {
        long test =Integer.valueOf("9007199254");   
        System.out.println("num :"+test); 
    }catch(NumberFormatException e)
    {
        System.out.println("Error..."+e.toString());
    }

}
```

}

Comment: try with `long`

Comment: long also gives same exception

Comment: try `Long.valueOf` not `Integer`

Comment: `int` limit is till `2,147,483,647`

Comment: its working..... thanx

Comment: than accept my answer please.

Comment: If your number is to conver to int or long, you can conver it to  the `BigInteger` to do it

Answer (score 2):

> But it gives Number Format Exception for more than 9 digit number.

Consider using `long` type as your number is greater than integer max range (2,147,483,647).

```
long test =Long.valueOf("9007199254");
```

Comment: Error...java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "9007199254"

Comment: @parimal Not left side, right side also you have to change.

Answer (score 1):

`int` limit is `2,147,483,647` thats why it gives `NumberFormatException`

try with `long`

```
long test =Long.valueOf("9007199254");
```